# Установка flask под venv

Tags: python, windows, flask, pip, virtualenv

Нужно написать приложение на flask. ранее с ним не работал, соответственно установлен не был. пользуюсь Windows 10. установил venv. начал ставить flask и тут начались проблемы.

https://hastebin.com/futiwohosa.tex

flask решил установиться только со второго раза. между этими 2 установками я вроде как ничего не сделал кроме гугла. ну да ладно, подумал. начал писать что-то, попытался запустить:

https://hastebin.com/kehihabozu.tex

окей, гугл. мне посоветовали сделать следующее:

> это не проблема Python, а проблема Windows.
>
> Не хватает wheel в pypi для markupsafe.
>
> Придется вам вручную ставить:
>   git clone git@github.com:pallets/markupsafe.git /c/tmp/markupsafe
>   cd /c/tmp/markupsafe
>   ./setup.py bdist_wheel
>
> результатом будет нормальный wheel:
>   /c/tmp/markupsafe/dist/MarkupSafe-1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
>
> потом устанавливаете его через pip:
>   pip install /c/tmp/markupsafe/dist/MarkupSafe-1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
>
> Пути, естественно, ваши.
>
> Затем ставите flask

хорошо.

https://hastebin.com/cutovujufi.lua

попробовал без венва

https://hastebin.com/nuhaviquni.tex

посчитал, что так и должно быть и пошёл дальше.

https://hastebin.com/izijohafam.tex

а вот, что вообще есть в venv.

https://hastebin.com/joqesazicu.css

то есть, фласк есть, пип последний... что я делаю не так?

Comment: К сожалению, разработка на питоне под виндой всегда будет содержать тысячи костылей. Проще поставить какой-нибудь докер, чем пытаться найти проблему.

Comment: мне уже помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, не до конца уверен, в чём была проблема, но следующее решение помогло:  установил предкомпилированный wheel [markupsafe](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#markupsafe),
и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поступил проще - поставил [Anaconda дистрибутив](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

После этого создаете VirtualEnv's:

```
conda update conda

conda create -n flask python=3.6

conda install flask markupsafe -n flask
```

Если `conda` не находит нужный пакет, попробуйте так:

```
anaconda -t conda search package_name
```

дальше следуйте инструкциям...

Чтобы активировать окружение:

```
activate flask
```